# JSON shows string type in behalf of bit/boolean field

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

```
{
  "Status": true,
  "Message": "Roles retrieved successfully",
  "Data": [
    {
      "RoleID": 1,
      "Role": "Super Admin",
      "IsPredefined": "1",
      "IsActive"    : "1",
    }
  ]
}
```

I am fetching above results in json format. I am using below query to fetch the data from MySql database.

I am using Model and my code is: `RoleModel::all()`

I am using PHP-Laravel 5.3

Is there any way to make the resultset like below.

```
{
  "Status": true,
  "Message": "Roles retrieved successfully",
  "Data": [
    {
      "RoleID": 1,
      "Role": "Super Admin",
      "IsPredefined": true,
      "IsActive"    : true,
    }
  ]
}
```

Issue is in IsPredefined. I want to retrieve it Boolean type. In database it is of type bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **[Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)**

**My model was like below**

```
class RoleModel extends Model {

    public $table = 'tblrole';
    public $primaryKey = 'RoleID';
    public $timestamps = true;

}
```

**It should be like below.**

```
class RoleModel extends Model {

    public $table = 'tblrole';
    public $primaryKey = 'RoleID';
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $casts = [
        'IsPredefined'  => 'boolean'
    ];
 }
```

> Moreover, Database table must have datatype = 'BIT' for boolean values
>   so that it may occupy only 0 or 1 values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [if()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function, so

```
Select RoleID, Role, if(IsPredefined=1,'true','false') as IsPredefined form tblrole;
```

If you are using Eloquent model you can use [**Accessors** and Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#introduction) so add accessor method in your eloquent model.

```
public function getIspredefinedAttribute($value)
{
    return ($value==1)?true:false;
}
```

Comment: I am using Model and my code is: `RoleModel::all()` So, it is not feasible to use this solution.

Comment: You can use Accessors for that. see updated answers.